# Сравнительный оборот или уподобление?

Tags: синтаксис

Немного искажу классика, чтобы не отвлекать от главного вопроса:

---

> "За Павла Ивановича я ручаюсь, как за самого себя".

Я бы в этом предложении не ставил запятую, поскольку не вижу здесь явного сравнения:

> "Я ручаюсь, словно за себя..."/"Я ручаюсь, будто за себя..."

Обычно при наличии сравнения такие фразы не выглядят абсурдными.
Я бы выделил здесь значение отождествления и не поставил запятую.
Тогда остается вопрос: почему Гоголь ее здесь поставил?

Comment: Заметил кое-что очень сложное в вашем предложении: *Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например "привлекательность".* Не хотелось прямо там писать. Лучше подальше, а потом можно будет удалить. Здесь же не обособленный оборот, а простое предложение: *Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например, "привлекательность" [подойдёт].* Не найти же легко "привлекательность", нет грамматической связи с глаголом "найти". Раньше с таким не сталкивался, поэтому захотелось осветить этот момент. Случай интересный. То есть запятая нужна, если следовать правилам Розенталя.

Comment: Для меня это присоединительный оборот/например привлекательность/. Поскольку "привлекательность"  взял в кавычки, считаю, что обезопасил себя. Кавычки дают право согласовать в речи несогласуемые слова.  А почему вы решили, что нужна запятая? "Например" стоит в начале оборота, запятая не нужна.

Comment: "...Калиостро без всяких трудов из всех других металлов, например из меди, прикосновением рук превращая их в золото". Позиция у слова "например" та же: оно служит для присоединения элемента.

Comment: В этом примере да, но в вашем нет. Присоединительный: *Ему нужны сладости, например печенье. В магазине можно найти сладости, например печенье.* Сказуемое можно повторить, а в вашем примере это не подходит: *Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например [можно легко найти] "привлекательность".* Сказуемое из первого предложения здесь не подходит, поэтому это не обособленный оборот. Внешне они не отличимы, нужно смотреть по сказуемому.

Comment: Для меня фраза найти "привлекательность" вполне логична. Ведь вы же анализируете слово, взятое в кавычки: оно расширяет свое значение.

Comment: Там не это, там: *Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например, подходит "привлекательность".* То есть другой глагол. Другая интерпретация некорректна в плане стилистики (*можно легко найти признак "привлекательность"*).

Comment: Здесь нет расширения значения, здесь просто опущено родовое слово: *[признак] "привлекательность"*. И ещё: в кавычки его брать не стоило, потому что такая форма сама по себе является признаком. Но это всё продвинутые вещи.

Comment: Обратите внимание на то, что у Розенталя нет кавычек.

Comment: Вы изменяете посыл предложения. Если вы поставите сюда глагол "подходит", то вводное слово тут будет точно лишним. Представьте себе этот набор слов: признак, например, подходит. Это нелепо выглядит и совсем нелепо звучит. Я бы был с вами согласен, если бы слово "привлекательность" стояло бы без кавычек, но это не так, поэтому к стилю тут не совсем корректно апеллировать.

Comment: Найти признак - найти "привлекательность". Вот в этом суть моего предложения. Вы уже додумали)))

Comment: "Привлекательность" - это признак, мы ее тоже "нашли", но в речи это звучит некорректно, поэтому я поставил кавычки, чтобы фраза была "законна".

Comment: Так никто не напишет в книжке. Это не нормально, кавычки не помогут. То есть вы хотите этот смысл? *Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например, можно легко найти признак "привлекательность".* Но это тупо. Это не естественный вариант, а какой-то странный. Главное, чтобы вы понимали разницу. Если вы понимаете, то можно заканчивать и удалять комментарии.

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю, почему вы не считаете /например привлекательность/ присоединением? "Никто не напишет", - я же написал))Если вы хотите полный вариант, я бы написал так: можно легко найти такой признак, как привлекательность.

Comment: "Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например, можно легко найти признак "привлекательность". Здесь вы сами кучу речевых ошибок наделали, мы же используем неполные предложения. И вы снова поставили "например" в несвойственное для него положение.

Comment: Имею в виду литературу. Мы же обсуждаем литературный язык. Не то что не считаю присоединением, а не считаю этот вариант естественным, лучше как бы добавить новый глагол и опустить его, тогда это нормальный русский язык. Не надо никаких извращений. Эта структура плохая, её нельзя назвать грамотной. Да какие речевые ошибки! Просто показываю заложенный смысл. Нормальная интерпретация: *Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например, [подходит] привлекательность.* Так можно написать в книге. Ваш вариант нельзя использовать в книге, он разговорный и странный.

Comment: *мы же используем неполные предложения* — ну да, вот и дополняю их, чтобы было понятно, что получается.

Comment: Полнота порой сильно искажает то, что заложено изначально.

Comment: Если мы берем ваш вариант с новым глаголом, то "например" оказывается не на своем месте. Для чего  оно будет там стоять? Это еще более неудачный вариант, по моему мнению.

Comment: Здесь ничего не искажает. Стоп! Оборот же не является неполным предложением, он входит в простое предложение. Если неполное, то предложение сложное, а оно простое, если не ставить запятую (сказуемое общее).

Comment: Да, но вы сделали из него полное предложение.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что изначально был только присоединительный оборот.

Comment: На своём месте оно, не знаю, с чего вы взяли. За счёт этой запятой освобождаемся от "можно легко найти", потом уже даём пример того, что нашли (а не того, что можно легко найти). Тогда всё логично.

Comment: У вас и "например", и " подходит" обозначают одно и то же. Вы ставите их вместе. Зачем?

Comment: Не обозначают. *Для примера подойдёт* — это корректно. Ну возьмите другой глагол. Смысл в том, чтобы освободиться от "можно легко найти" и потом сказать о том, что вы нашли. Это логично.

Comment: И я уже писал: для меня ваш пример с новым глаголом  - это серия из трех несвязанных понятий: признак-например-подходит.

Comment: Вы же используете не "для примера", а вводное слово, которое имеет свое значение. Ваш глагол уже поясняет то, что было сказано до этого. "Например" какой тогда цели служит?

Comment: Да без разницы. Переставьте: *подходит, например, это*. Это же свойство, которое вы нашли. И смысл об этом сообщить (о том, что оно найдено), а не о том, что его можно легко найти.

Comment: Употр. как вводное слово при перечислении, при пояснении слова в предложении, для иллюстрации предшествующего изложения.

Comment: Оно для того, чтобы показать, что это пример. То есть не просто подходит, а что это пример "подхождения". Всё корректно.

Comment: Все же считаю, что ваш пример сильно искажает включенные в предложение смыслы.

Comment: Какой пример? Ваш смысл в том, что это свойство легко найти, а не в том, что вы нашли такое свойство?

Comment: С "подходит" и "например".

Comment: Заочно соглашусь с вами, однако узнаю и другие мнения экспертов. Пусть они тоже дадут оценку, корректно ли предложение, которое было изначально.

Comment: Ничего лучше не придумал. Можно так: *Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например, их связывает привлекательность. Тут легко можно найти такой признак, например, возьмём привлекательность.* Его можно посчитать корректным, но оно точно не для книг и не очень удачно. А где вы найдёте экспертов? Кто, по-вашему, эксперты? Вряд ли вы найдёте учёных (кандидатов, докторов).

Comment: Мне показалось, что вы однозначно имели в виду не то, что этот признак можно легко найти. Логично сказать о том, что вы нашли такой признак.

Comment: Я же сам филолог, поэтому я на дружеской ноге с синтаксистами. Среди них есть и доценты, и профессоры. Обязательно потом отпишусь, что они ответили.

Comment: Прикольно тогда. Им тогда надо с нашим диалогом ознакомиться, или нет?

Comment: Удаляем эти комментарии? Они ведь к этому вопросу никакого отношения не имеют. А то их в чат переместят, а потом уже нельзя будет удалить.

Comment: Скорее всего надо)

Comment: Да не надо удалять.

Comment: Их точно в чат выкинут. Изначально планировал удалить. Можете заскриншотить, если хотите, чтобы они ознакомились.

Comment: Ок. Так и сделаю.

Comment: Изначальный вариант корректный, просто нелогичный. Похоже на это: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472511 (обсуждение в чате). И стилистика неудачная. В книгах такой смысл бы не закладывали. Может, и не стоит спрашивать (раз корректный). Написал, потому что был уверен, что вы имели в виду другое.

Comment: Удаляем уже?...

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. Вот именно, что отождествление. По грамматике без запятой получается отождествление себя и Павла Ивановича.

Пример:
*За него ручаюсь как за друга.* || Он является другом. Значение "в качестве":
*За него в качестве друга ручаюсь.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139650/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd----).